# Tooltip on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

How can I show an error message using tooltip on click of a button and that too if there is error, else the button should just work fine to submit the form?

Here is what I have tried with modal dialog

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
 $('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen:false,show:'blind',hide:'explode'});
 $('#savej').click(function(){$('#dialog').dialog('open');return false;});
});
```

Comment: How does Java factor into this?

Comment: well ..my form submission is in java. So I just added that as a tag.I know it's not related to that.

Comment: java and javascript are two different "animals"

Comment: must it use a tooltip.  or would a modal dialog be useful.

Comment: What code do you have so far for your submit function?

Comment: I was creating a div element containing my error message and adding it to form when submit is pressed. I was trying to use dialog which will be called when that submit is pressed and will show the error message in dialog box. But somehow it didn't work. Tooltip is nice, dialog is kind of annoying for users.

Comment: @John- how will you do that with modal dialog?I tried with dialog, but it didn't work.

Comment: if you were using jquery ui the dialog is either modal or not.  Perhaps if you want to use a modal dialog repost the code that you did have a problem with then it would be easier to see what you were doing wrong.

Comment: @John - I added the code which I was trying from Jquery UI dialog.

Comment: @yogsma....can i see the html for the save button.  and where are you loading the error message into the dialog?

Comment: @John - I sorted out. Thanks for your input. The problem was the DIV element , I was loading when the button was clicked and not default. When I loaded the DIV element default and hidden, that modal dialog worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#savej').click(function(e){
    if (hasErrors()) { // Some checking for errors
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    }
});
```